# Safari grid element shrinks on zoom

Tags: css, safari

I am developing a series of custom checkboxes and radio buttons for my project. I have found that, on Safari, when I zoom in on the page, the radio and check elements do not scale as I expect, which is to increase in size linearly. On Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, my components scale as I expect:

[image: chrome firefox edge original size]
[image: chrome firefox edge zoomed]

However, on Safari, the radio and check elements get smaller as I zoom in:

[image: safari original size]

[image: safari zoomed]

The radio and check elements exist in a Grid context and their width and height is defined in `rem`. The checkbox and radio buttons themselves are flexbox containers with `svg` checkmarks. The label text size is also defined in `rem`.

```css
div.control-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-cols: auto 1fr;
  justify-content: start;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
}

.radio-element, .checkbox-element {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.checkbox-element.small, .radio-element.small {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

The HTML structure generally follows this pattern:

```
label
  input (hidden)
  div.control-grid
    div.{checkbox,radio}-element
      svg (checkmark)
    p (label text)
```

What is causing the zoom behavior to be different on Safari? Is it the `REM` sizing or the grid / flexbox definitions? I found another answer about `text-size-adjust`, but that applies to Safari on iOS, not desktop Safari (v15.1). Not sure where to start here. Thanks.

Browsers used: Safari 15.1, Chrome 96, Edge 96, Firefox 95. Testing in Storybook, project is using React, NextJS, and TailwindCSS.

**Edit: Add full HTML markup as rendered on the page:**

```html
<label class="radio-container " data-testid="radio-label-container">
  <input type="radio" name="options" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="label_for_options" value="Option 1">
  <div class="control-grid">
    <div class="radio-element border-Gray300 text-Primary900 small  ">
      <svg class="m-1" width="6" height="6" data-testid="radio-fill" viewBox="0 0 6 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="3" cy="3" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <p class="text-black text-p3 label-text font-medium text-Gray700" id="label_for_options">Option 1</p>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide the actual HTML instead of the pattern?

Comment: @Kameron my project is built with React. Are you looking for the template that is returned by my react component, or the html structure as rendered on the page?

Comment: either works for me.

Comment: @Kameron added rendered html markup